# Jira Install issues on ubuntu

Tags: java, mysql, jira

Could not find driver with class name: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

```
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-nyc1-01:~# ls
atlassian-jira-software-7.2.0-x64.bin mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.tar.gz
mysql-connector-java-5.1.39 mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.tar.gz.1
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-nyc1-01:~#
```

I can see the SQL connector is installed but cannot run this command

```
cd /tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39
```

I'm newer to linux so please tell me what I'm not doing correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have verified the SQL connector is in the tmp folder but still having issues.

Comment: how did you verify that?

Answer (score 0):

`root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-nyc1-01:~# ls` - look at the part between : and # - this is your current directory. ~ is a shorthand for home directory, which is `/root` for the user root. Thus the directory you need is `/root/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39`, not `/tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39`

Try `cd mysql-connector-java-5.1.39` or `cd /root/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39`

Comment: @Chance yes, "No such file or directory" if you entered a wrong path or "Not a directory" if you try to cd to a file